# To prove that the integral is the sum of a formula

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

I want to prove that $$\int_0^1x^{-x}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-n}$$ And I know that $$x^{-x}=e^{-x\log x}$$ and $$e^u=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{u^n}{n!}$$ I get that $$x^{-x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-x\log x)^n}{n!}$$

Then I have no idea how to prove the rest of it. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream

Answer (score 0):

Exchange the order of integration and summation.  Then, make the change of variables $ u  = -ln(x)$.

Comment: To do that one would have to have an integration and a summation in the same term. Where do you see that in the question?

Comment: Do you mean to substitute the right-hand side of the last equation and substitute it into the integral on the left-hand side of the first equation?